# For each element inside an array I want it to have another for each that will have unique action

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to make each element inside myArray will have it's unique action, but I end up with only one of them working.
I have tried one more way of doing it that worked, but it was a complete boilerplate and I'm looking for a better solution than that.
More details:
For each element (Another array of buttons) inside myArray it will have unique action like scrollIntoView of some element in HTML.

In HTML I have 4 divs that share the same class and it looks like that:

```
<div class='firstDiv'>
<button class="teamBtn"></button>
<button class="serviceBtn"></button>
etc..
</div>
<div class='secondDiv'>
<button class="teamBtn"></button>
<button class="serviceBtn"></button>
etc..
</div>
```

```
let aboutSection = document.querySelector('.about')
let serviceSection = document.querySelector('.services')
let teamSection = document.querySelector('.team')
let homeBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.homeBtn');
let aboutBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.aboutBtn');
let serviceBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.serviceBtn')
let teamBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.teamBtn')

let myArray = [];

myArray[0] = homeBtn;
myArray[1] = aboutBtn;
myArray[2] = serviceBtn;
myArray[3] = teamBtn;
```

```
myArray.forEach(el => {
  addEventListener('click', () => {
    teamBtn.forEach(() => {
     teamSection.scrollIntoView();
    });
    serviceBtn.forEach(() => {
      serviceSection.scrollIntoView();
    });

  })
})
```

Comment: There is nothing to be gained from putting the buttons in an array, and then trying to give each array item its own special treatment. You need to forget about the array, at least for this purpose. Just use 7 lines of code like `someButton.addEventListener('click', function () { ...... } );`. And use `document.querySelector(....)` everywhere because it returns the first matching element, instead of a collection of elements.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList. That you assign to an array-element. Then you loop the array and try to assign a eventListener to each element. So basically you're trying to attach a eventListener to a NodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want delegation from a container wrapping ALL divs. Then only one event handler is needed for all buttons

```js
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button")
  if (tgt && (tgt.classList.contains("teamBtn") ||tgt.classList.contains("serviceBtn"))) {
    document.getElementById(tgt.dataset.id).scrollIntoView();
  } 
})
```

```css
section div {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <div class="firstDiv">
    <button class="teamBtn" data-id="team1">Team 1</button>
    <button class="serviceBtn" data-id="service1">Service 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="secondDiv">
    <button class="teamBtn" data-id="team2">team 2</button>
    <button class="serviceBtn" data-id="service2">Service 2</button>
  </div>
</nav>
<section id="content1">
  <div id="team1">Team 1</div>
  <div id="service1">Service 1</div>
</section>
<section id="content2">
  <div id="team2">Team 2</div>
  <div id="service2">Service 2</div>
</section>
```